# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED and SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE when working with URLs in Databricks Python Script

Tags: python, json, ssl, urllib, databricks

I am using Databricks to parse JSON data from a URL using Python Version 3.  The URL of interest:

```
https://www.example.com/data/example.json
```

actually produces output in a JSON file to be downloaded, rather than JSON text in the browser.  Note that it is https.  Here is a simplified version of the Python code.

```
import json
import urllib
import requests

url = "https://www.example.com/data/example.json"
json_text = requests.get(url).text
response = json.loads(json_text)
```

When Databricks tries to execute the
    json_text = requests.get(url).text
statement, I have gotten one of the following errors:

```
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

or

```
SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
```

It appears that Databricks cannot access that URL for some reason.  I am not sure why I would need a certificate to do so.  Does Databricks require some SSL or PKI certificate to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your old python version is creating the issue. The better solution is to update its version and try the same python code again.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using Python Version 3.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I will need to use Python to pass my PKI certificates so that I can use the URL.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you resolved this issue. Thanks!